# Help fix screen tearing if external monitor orientation is changed

Tags: arch-linux, kde, manjaro

I have a laptop and I added one external monitor, everything is perfect when the screen orientation of the external display is default landscape, but as soon I change it to 90 deg clockwise or counterclockwise, It will start to screen tearing. It will only screen tear if switch to that orientation, otherwise if set it back to normal orientation the screen tearing is gone.

BTW I am on manjaro on KDE plasma edition. My laptop screen resolution is 1920x1080 while the external monitor is 1366x768.

Comment: X11 or Wayland? If you are using X11, try Wayland to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @JohanMyréen I am on X11, I'm not to keen installing wayland but I will try.

Comment: On Manjaro, enabling Wayland should be as simple as installing the package `plasma-wayland-session`, which pulls in a few extra packages as dependencies. After logging out, you should be able to choose between a Wayland session and an X11 session from the display manager (at least if you use SDDM, which they say is the recommended display manager for Plasma.)

Comment: Thanks! it works, the screen tearing is gone. But got another issue, my cursor is not accurate anymore most notable in konsole, when I tried to highlight a text, it will highlight the text above/previous line.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Is the offset exactly one line, or something a little bit above or below one line? Have you updated your system recently? KDE bugs have been fixed recently, though I couldn't find any bug entry that matches your description.

Comment: Have you installed a custom cursor theme? There could be a problem with the hot spot defined by the cursor.

Comment: @JohanMyréen in konsole I think it is one line offset. on other kde apps like the system settings, I need to move the cursor below the item I want to click. I think  it is not "a little bit" because I need to move the cursor below at least one cursor height.

Comment: Yes my system is updated, btw i am using stable version of Manjaro. My KDE plasma version is 5.19.3, kde framework is 5.72 and QT version is 5.15. Also I didn't install any custom cursor theme.